# Reading NPY/NPZ files from GCP in TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

Is it possible to read NPY or NPZ files from Google Cloud Platform (GCP) storage and get features data stored in these numpy files into datasets while using TPU?

The main requirement for TPU is to use data from Google Cloud by datasets. My image features that are extracted from InceptionV3 are stored in numpy files and since TPU needs these files to be read from cloud, I stored this data on GCP storage.

Now, what I am trying to do is - I have list of filepath which I am passing to map() function from where I want the numpy files specified by this filepath to get loaded and this numpy data (image features) to be added in dataset.

Original code was not using TPU so it was using following statements to load numpy.

```
def map_func(img_name, cap):
  img_tensor = np.load(img_name.decode('utf-8')+'.npy')
  return img_tensor, cap
```

and for calling map function on dataset, following code was used -

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda item1, item2: tf.numpy_function(
  map_func, [item1, item2], [tf.float32, tf.int32]),
  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

But for TPU, I cannot use this code as it is using `np.load()` function which does not work on `gs://` type of URL. Also, calling numpy_function generates errors for TPU implementations.

So, what I did is - I converted this numpy function call to the simple function call as follows -

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(map_func, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

So, this is pure tensorflow type of function call in which we get tensors inside map_func(). So I made changes in map_func() accordingly as follows.

```
f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string('gs://my-bucket/data.npz', binary_mode=True))
data = np.load(f)
```

Above function works with Google Cloud path, however when I call `np.load()`, it says you haven't set `allow_pickle` flag to True. Once, I set this flag to True, it gives error that pickle for BytesIO type of data is not available.

I got another code to read these files from Google Cloud which works if called directly, but does not work with map_func() callback function since all the variables becomes tensors.

```
f_stream = file_io.FileIO('image_file.npz', 'rb')
d = np.load( BytesIO(f_stream.read()) )
```

Please suggest is there any standard way of loading features from NPY/NPZ files stored on GCP storage under TPU.

Comment: Can't you convert your npy/npz files to [TFRecord format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord)? That should be straightforward to process.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.. was just thinking on the same lines.. let me try that..